# Laravel Symfony NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm getting an interesting issue with laravel, some routes works well, some returns 404, it's strange but see examples below.

This is an examples when **routes works well:**

```
Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin'));
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));
```

But this **route returns error:**

```
Route::get('import', array('uses'=>'ImportController@importForm'));
```

**Controller:**

```
class ImportController extends BaseController {

public function importForm() {
    return "Import From";
}
```

### **Stacktrace:**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#11 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in     /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
#10 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1049
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1017
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:996
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:776
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:746
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:72
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php:47
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php:51
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in /var/www/html/inventory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:642
```

---

It's strange isn't it?

So then I tried to add route like default one (You have arrived):

```
Route::get('/', function() {return View::make('hello');}); //WORKS WELL
Route::get('/sku', function() {return View::make('hello');}); //DOES'N WORK :)
```

Please take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong guys?

**Thanks and Happy New Year!**

**UPDATES:**

THESE ROUTES ALSO WORKS WELL:

```
Route::get('orders', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@showOrdersTable'));
Route::get('api/orders', array('as'=>'api.orders', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@getOrdersDatatableJSON'));
Route::match(array("POST", "GET"), 'api/orders/note/save', array('as'=>'api.note', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@saveNote'));
Route::match(array("POST", "GET"), 'api/orders/tracking/save', array('as'=>'api.tracking', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@saveTracking'));
Route::match(array("POST", "GET"), 'api/orders/status/update', array('as'=>'api.status', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@updateStatus'));
Route::match(array("POST", "GET"), 'system/update', array('as'=>'api.update.system', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@updateDatabase'));
```

Comment: I'd guess you don't have your mod_rewrite rules in place correctly. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's strange but I have more routes and these routes works well... also I enabled mod_rewrite. http://localhost/login - WORKS , http://localhost/sku - NOP ))

Comment: What other routes do you have? Any catch-alls?

Comment: The full contents of your `routes.php` file might be helpful.

Comment: I added some updates on description, there are some routes that works well, Thanks

Comment: Route::get('orders', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@showOrdersTable'));
Route::get('testorders', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses'=>'InventoryController@showOrdersTable')); Two absolutely the same routes first one works second doesn't. All routes that I'm adding today doesn't works

Comment: i think you have some problems with cache. as php 5.4 implicit opcache is enabled.

Comment: for test purpose, just look throught terminal (cmd) `php artisan routes`

Comment: Thank you for answer Maximilian, I checked in php artisan routes table and it's there. Also tried composer clearcache, artisan clearcache... nothing... Should I create new Laravel project and move my code? how do you think guys? If I create new project on the same server and add new routes it works, something is broken but I can't understand what...

Comment: <?php 
    opcache_reset();
?>, server reboot, reset to old commits, some of this actions fixed it. So strange. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order and see if it makes any difference. Like:

```
Route::get('/sku', function() {return View::make('hello');});     
Route::get('/', function() {return View::make('hello');});
```

Comment: No it was something different, I reset my git repository to older commits and added all routes again, now it works. Maybe I copied some hidden symbols to my code, I don't know :(